# MinGW Windows.h does not compile

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, include

I'm using MinGW g++ 4.6.2 on 64 bit Windows 7. As for IDE, I use Eclipse CDT.

I have a problem with my project - when I include "Windows.h" file, I'm getting thousands of errors. I tried to create a diffrent file with only Windows.h included but it gives same errors.

.h:

```
/*
 * WinWrapper.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 24, 2013
 *      Author: martin
 */

#ifndef WINWRAPPER_H_
#define WINWRAPPER_H_

char* winGetMainModule();

#endif /* WINWRAPPER_H_ */
```

.cpp:

```
#include "WinWrapper.h"

#include <windows.h>

char* winGetMainModule() {



    return nullptr;

}
```

no other files include "WinWrapper.h" nor Windows.h.

```
template with C linkage GameProj        line 172, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.tcc C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 228, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.tcc C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 128, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.tcc C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 133, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.tcc C/C++ Problem
confused by earlier errors, bailing out GameProj        line 118, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h C/C++ Problem
declaration of C function 'constexpr std::_Ios_Openmode std::operator&(std::_Ios_Openmode, std::_Ios_Openmode)' conflicts with  GameProj        line 117, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h C/C++ Problem
previous declaration 'constexpr std::_Ios_Fmtflags std::operator&(std::_Ios_Fmtflags, std::_Ios_Fmtflags)' here GameProj        line 77, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h  C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 614, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 623, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 629, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 636, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 592, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 598, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
template with C linkage GameProj        line 602, external location: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\type_traits C/C++ Problem
```

... + around 200 KB of other error logs

Other project info:

1. using libraries SDL, SDL_Image
2. defined TARGET_WINX86
3. compiler flags -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x

No idea whats going on. Please help, thanks in advance :))

Comment: a bit weird, but it does sound as if you're using `gcc` instead of `g++` in your build command. why don't you show your build command.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SfEhHXcT thanks for willing to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> from C:\workspace\GameProj\src\Base/string.h

↑ culprit.

you have your own `string.h` file which, due to the include paths, is being picked up by an include from `winnt.h`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I wish C++ would be less error-prone, many thanks for you :))